# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined - when trying to JointJS Hello World example

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jointjs

I'm trying to get the JointJS 'Hello World' example to work

Reference: https://resources.jointjs.com/tutorial/hello-world

The dependencies are all loaded in the correct order but I can't get around the following exception: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` when trying to run the example.

I realize that Backbone requires underscore but I read in a different article that Backbone 1.3.3 should be compatible with Lodash. When I do include underscore it seems to conflict with lodash (which jointjs requires). eg. '_.create is not defined'.

I've tried a multitude of different versions to no avail.

Here's a jsfiddle where I'm trying to get it to work in.

https://jsfiddle.net/0mdg8xja/1/

What am I doing wrong and how can I get around this exception in this scenario?

Comment: I do know that migrating everything from underscore to lodash doesn't even solve this problem.  When I was looking into it, I think JointJS required some custom build of lodash, but I'm not sure.  I gave up and went with GoJS.

Comment: I hadn't ran into GoJS yet, looks promising. If I can't seem to solve this problem I think I might just go for GoJS as well. Thanks.

Comment: Please favor on-site stack snippet over off-site resources like jsfiddle, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to the idea of looking up existing JSFiddles and stumbled upon this one:

https://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/gfaL9ype/

I compared the hello world example to this one and it appears that the only thing I was missing was the fact that I had to wrap the javascript inside:

```
$(function(){ });
```

This seems to work regardless of what versions I use. I tested it on JointJS `0.9.7` and `1.1.0`, backbone `1.1`, `1.3.3` and lodash `3.10.1`.

Here's the updated JSFiddle for if anyone stumbled upon the same foreheadsmacker as I did.

https://jsfiddle.net/gfaL9ype/30/

Comment: [`$(function(){ });` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){});`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) which means that you were trying to get `$('#myholder')` before it actually existed in the DOM.

Comment: its becasue of lodash version. jointjs is using _.each function's 3 argument (this) , that got removed in lodash newer version.